# Complex SQL query on javascript object

Tags: javascript, sql

I have the following JS object:

```
var groups = [{id="4", name="abcd", id_group="1"},
              {id="5", name="efgh", id_group="1"},
              {id="6", name="ijkl", id_group="1"},
              {id="4", name="abcd", id_group="2"},
              {id="7", name="mnop", id_group="2"}]
```

And I need to execute this SQL query on above-mentioned object:

```
select id_group from groups where id in (4,7) 
group by id_group having count(distinct id) = 2
```

Result should be:

```
id_group="2"
```

because only that group contains the both ids using in query.

I found information about [SQLike](http://www.thomasfrank.se/sqlike.html) and [JSLINQ](http://jslinq.codeplex.com/) but I have encountered problems with *where in* and *having* expressions. Is there any possibility to execute such query on javascript object using SQL-JS libraries or JS/jQuery itself (writing function etc.)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) JavaScript SQL library was especially designed for this type of tasks:

```
<script src="alasql.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var groups = [{id:4, name:"abcd", id_group:"1"},
          {id:5, name:"efgh", id_group:"1"},
          {id:6, name:"ijkl", id_group:"1"},
          {id:4, name:"abcd", id_group:"2"},
          {id:7, name:"mnop", id_group:"2"}];

    var res = alasql('select id_group, count(id) as cnt from ? \
        where id in (4,7) group by id_group having cnt = 2',[groups]); 
</script>
```

You can try [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/5prbwtzy/1/) in jsFiddle.

I modified a little bit a SQL expression, because Alasql do not support aggregator functions (like COUNT, SUM, MAX, MIN) inside HAVING clause.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you are asking, but using jQuery you can filter the groups object as follows:

```js
var filteredArr = $.grep(groups, function(obj, index) {
   return obj.id_group === "2"
});
```

Hope that helped.